# How to show Json data in TableviewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am getting this data from the **Webservice**

```
dict : {
    "Apparel & Accessories" = 2;
    "Automotive Services" = 0;
    "Building and Construction" = 1;
    "Business & Professional Services" = 0;
    "Business Services" = 0;
    "Community & Education" = 0;
    Education = 0;
    "Entertainment & Media" = 2;
    FREIGHT = 0;
    "Family & Community" = 0;
    Finance = 0;
    "Finance & Legal" = 1;
    "Food & Dining" = 3;
    "Health & Medicine" = 2;
    "Home & Garden" = 0;
    "Home Repair & Improvement" = 0;
    "Industrial supplies & services" = 0;
    "Information Technology" = 1;
    Legal = 0;
    PELLETS = 0;
    "Personal Care" = 2;
    "Public utilities & environment" = 0;
    "Real Estate" = 0;
    "Real Estate & Insurance" = 0;
    Shopping = 0;
    "Shopping & Specialty Stores" = 0;
    "Sports & Recreation" = 0;
    "TRANSPORT SERVICES" = 0;
    Transportation = 0;
    Travel = 1;
    "Travel & Lodging" = 0;
    Uncategorized = 0;
}
```

and i have to display this data in the tableview according to image given below

[image]

Please tell me what to do, i am not getting idea to do this...
Thanks

Comment: I am not asking for code am just asking for idea what to do to get these values in front of the keys... @FawadMasud, i already got all the keys in the tableview

Comment: I suggest that you buy a book about programming.

Comment: To parse json this is helpful tutorial. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can gave you the idea how you can do this - just add the required keys in array.For e.g.: Education,freight Then you can show the data from array in table view.

Comment: ok i got it, i have done this like NSArray *valuesArray = [dictTemp allValues];NSArray *keysArray = [dictTemp allKeys]; , and show these key and values in the tableview cell

Comment: Correct. You just have to show those values from array.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *key = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",key,[dict objectForKey:key]];
```

;